# Is it ok to use <label> in other nesting level than its <input> control layout?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I want to know if the following HTML/CSS is wrong by any means, mainly from accessibility point of view.

I have two set of instructions A and B. The user only sees one of them at a time. When the user sees instructions A, there should be a link to B, and vice-versa. 
I thought on using `<radio>` buttons and their `:checked` state to control the visibility of the content, and then the `<label>` could be inside that content, acting as the link. Since labels can be clicked to activate its corresponding radio button, I setup the code like this:

```css
label {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.a,.b {
  display:none;
}

#a:checked ~ .content .a,
#b:checked ~ .content .b {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="options" value="a" id="a" checked>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="b" id="b">

<div class="content">
  <div class="a">
    Some text and <label for="b">Check out B</label>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Some other text and <label for="a">Check out A</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since this seems very hackish, I thought you could point out any potential problems this code could lead into.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any particular constraint concerning the HTML label tag, that would prevent you to do what you have done.
The only constraint that is stated on [W3S HTML label tag page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) is that its « `for` attribute must be equal to the `id` attribute of the related element to bind them together. »

And you observed it. So there should not be any problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not accessible as it would require to click an item in order to view its description.

This won't work with a screenreader.

The screenreader will want to find the text alternative for both elements at the same time, and the description being invisible, one will always be without a text alternative.